# How to set properties of a List<Class> in C#

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I have a class defined as such:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response2
{
    [DataMember(Name = "done")]
    public bool done;
    [DataMember(Name = "records")]
    public List<Response3> r3entry;
}

[DataContract]
public class Response3
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public string strId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string strName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what I'd like to happen is take the values from ANOTHER class and populate... something like this:

```
string propertyRequest2 = CreatePropertyRequest2();
Response2 propResponse2 = MakeRequest2(propertyRequest2, sfToken);

List<Response> listAllData = new List<Response>();

foreach (var responseEntry in propResponse2.r3entry)
{
    listAllData.Add(new Response() { strId = responseEntry.strId, strName = responseEntry.strName } );

    // NOTE .strId IS ALWAYS UNIQUE IN BOTH CLASSES
    // - I know this is NOT the right syntax... will fix later.
    Where listAllData.strId = responseEntry.strId
    {
        listAllData.property = propertyResponse2(.strId=responseEntry.strId).property
    }
}
```

I'm sure (at least) the last bit of the code is painful to most people reading this, but I will fix so it's not so terrible. I just don't know if explaining it is as clear.  Just in case I'm wrong, the point here is more like this:

```
// WE HAVE A LIST OF CLASSES WITH PROPERTIES
// ASSUME PROPERTIES ARE ID, ITEM, NAME
LIST1 = { ("1", "A", "APPLE"), ("2", "B", "BANANA"), ("3", "C", "COCONUT")}

// NOW WE HAVE ANOTHER LIST THAT HAS THE SAME ID BUT DIFF DATA
// ASSUME PROPERTIES ARE ID, COLOR
LIST2 = { ("1", "RED"), ("2", "YELLOW"), ("3", "BROWN) }

// AND THEN I WANT TO CREATE A NEW LIST WITH BOTH SETS OF DATA COMBINED
// ASSUME PROPERTIES ARE ID, ITEM, NAME, COLOR
LIST3 = { ("1", "A", "APPLE", "RED"), ("2", "B", "BANANA"), ("3", "C", "COCONUT", "BROWN") }
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are the properties known at compile time? (Do we know that the end result will have `id` `item` `name` and `color`?) Or can they be any properties? And if so, what happens with collisions (two objects have the same property name but different value) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join with projection:

```
var list = from l1 in LIST1
    join l2 in LIST2 on l1.ID equals l2.ID
    select new {
        l1.ID,
        l1.Item,
        l1.Name,
        l2.Color
    }
    .ToList()
```

Comment: ah, yes, that's what i'm after is a join. i wasn't aware you could do this inside C#. i thought that was only a SQL thing.

Comment: Look up some tutorials on LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what your goal is, the Zip function acts on two lists and returns the product of those two lists. You can read about it more here:

[Zip on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx)

But in effect, if you have two lists of things, lets say:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
// The following example concatenates corresponding elements of the
// two input sequences.
var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (first, second) => first + " " + second);
```

So in your case it might be something like this:

```
Response2[] response2 = //some list
Response3[] response3= // some other list
var response2Andresponse3 = response2.Zip(response3, (res2,res3) => //something you want to do with them
```

This will pair the first element of response2 with the first element of response3 and so on. We are also assuming here that they have the same length so that you don't have unpaired attributes.

You'll have to figure out a way to pipe this out to something you might find useful, but you will have a list where they correspond element by element.

Comment: with `Enumerable.Zip()` must the elements be in the same order? i'm also not clear how this would work on multidimensional arrays...

Comment: Zip will zip them together in order so you would have to know their order before hand. If you wanted multidimensionality i.e triplets and n-tuples, you would just chain a zips onto other. However, your example is with classes, not with n-dimensional arrays, so I am wondering what you mean by multidimensionality.